# mongo db update script based on condition

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a mongo db collection of name `School`.The sample data is shown as below.

```
{
   "_id" = ObjectId("5349b4ddd2781d08c09890f4"),
  "school": [
    {
      "Class": [
        {
          "Name":{
            "Subject": [
              "C",
              "A"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
{
  "_id" = ObjectId("5349b4ddd2781d08c09890f5"),
  "school": [
    {
      "Class": [
        {
          "Name": {
            "Subject": [
              "B",
              "A",
              "C"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
{
  "_id" = ObjectId("5349b4ddd2781d08c09890f6"),
  "school": [
    {
      "Class": [
        {
          "Name": {
            "Subject": [
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
{
  "_id" = ObjectId("5349b4ddd2781d08c09890f7"),
  "school": [
    {
      "Class": [
        {
          "Name": {
            "Subject": [
              "C"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
{
  "_id" = ObjectId("5349b4ddd2781d08c09890f8"),
  "school": [
    {
      "Class": [
        {
          "Name": {
            "Subject":[
              "A"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

There can be only 2 subjects `A` and `B` in `Subject` list. I need to write a script which will check if there are any other subjects apart from `A` and `B` then it will remove that. If there are only 2 subjects `A` and `C` then `C` will be updated to `B`. If there are only 1 subject `C` then it will be replace by `B`. Keep as it is if `Subject` contains no value or `Subject` contains only `A`.

This is what I am trying to fetch relevant data to update but not sure how to update it in Mongo db with the above condition

```
db.getCollection("School").find(
{
  "$and": [
    {"school.Class.Name.Subject": {
       "$ne":null
      }
    },
    {"school.Class.Name.Subject": {
       "$in":[
         "C"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
);
```

Comment: Your documents have no `"_id"` to distinguish the schools?  Also, what did you mean by, "Keep as it is if `Subject `contains no value or `Subject` contains only `A`."?

Comment: Sorry It has _id .I havent mentioned here just to save time.Keep as it is means if there are no values in Subject [] then I dont want to update it.Only if C is there then it needs to be replaced and there can be only 2 subjects A and B and it would be distinct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data model makes this a bit complicated.  My example first filters for documents that only have `"C"` in the `"Subject"` array, then in the pipeline, it dives down into the structure with several `"$map"` until `"Subject"` is reached.  Here, `"Subject"` codes are check for `"C"` and if they are, they are replaced with `"B"`.  All the codes are aggregated with `"$setUnion"` so repeats won't appear.  `"multi"` at the end is needed with `update`, but `updateMany` could be used instead.

```js
db.collection.update({
  // Only need to update where "C" is present
  "school.Class.Name.Subject": "C"
},
[
  {
    // Recreate school taking care of "C"
    "$set": {
      "school": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$school",
          "as": "class",
          "in": {
            "Class": {
              "$map": {
                "input": "$$class.Class",
                "as": "name",
                "in": {
                  "Name": {
                    "Subject": {
                      "$setUnion": {
                        "$map": {
                          "input": "$$name.Name.Subject",
                          "as": "code",
                          "in": {
                            "$cond": [
                              { "$eq": [ "$$code", "C" ] },
                              "B",
                              "$$code"
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  // Do all docs (or use updateMany, etc.)
  "multi": true
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hfxsXV_XYEZ).

Comment: Thank you so much.Please give me some suggestion or share some links  how to learn Mongo DB to be able to write this type of query.I have good command in Sql but I find Mongo Db a little difficult

Comment: @vicky I'm still learning too.  Of course I Google "mongodb whatever" and then look at the documentation like [the reference manual for aggregation pipeline operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/).  I have my own query building tasks, but by far, I've enhanced my general knowledge by trying the challenges presented here as questions, like yours.  I've read and re-read more of the reference manual trying to answer questions here than trying to solve my own tasks. If you have time, try to answer some of the MongoDB questions here - I've learned a lot.